# Creating a static array with a variable size?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack, constants

I want to create an array which is not on the heap, but on the stack. The size of my array will be based on the number of lines in a file.

I found this SO post:

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Is there still no way to create an array on the stack where the size is determined by something else, other than a const?

Comment: Not in real C++.  But you can use the non-standard extensions in GCC.  I believe they are on by default.

Comment: What's the core problem you are you trying to solve? Why do you need it to be on the stack?

Comment: Take a look at this [llvm::SmallVector](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1SmallVector.html).  Does that tickle your fancy?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't create an array on the stack unless its size is known at compile time. Not just `const`, but compile-time constant.